# Angular, button validation work in the wrong order

Tags: angular, validation, checkbox, model

i have one checkbox in angular 7

when I refresh my page, the good value is here

but when I click the checkbox, the value is the wrong one

there is my code in my html :

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]=material.validated (click)="updateValidation(material)">
```

in my ts :

```
public updateValidation(material: any) {
    this.requestService.updateVersionQuotation(this.quotationId, this.versionId, this.quotation);
}
```

Comment: `material.validated` is false and when you click the checkbox, the `updateValidation` receive the value `material.validated` false instead of true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the HTML as follows

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="material.validated" (change)="updateValidation(material)">
```

Component as

```
material = {};
public updateValidation(material: any) {
    this.requestService.updateVersionQuotation(this.quotationId, this.versionId, this.quotation);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you listen to the click event, you don't listen to the input change, but to the click event, which happens before.

Try listening to the [correct event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) :

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="updateValidation()">
```

I have removed the `ngModel` binding because you don't seem to need it in your function, and you usually don't use both events and bindings to manage a single input.

Comment: Thanks, but need to keep the ngModel : that the default value

Comment: @BenjaminBarbé then you should use `[value]`.